# How to display k records and after that show vertical scroll bar datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable and my requirement is to display n records (5 records) on page and if there are more records then vertical scroll bar should appears.

I do not want to use paging feature of datatable.

Also while scrolling vetically wants to dispaly

```
Page 1 of 5
on 
Page 2 of 5
```

I have tried so many thing but not working

```
$('#example').dataTable({

                iDisplayLength: 5,
                scrollY: "200px",
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                ordering: false,
                searching: false,
                bInfo: false
            });
```

Comment: If you go to datatables forums it literally tells you what to turn off and on in the datatables init

Comment: You also need all of those in " ", so "scrollY": "200 px",

Comment: @clearshot66 yeah , i fixed that issue "200px"

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the datatables documentation:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

for scroll Y

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    } );
} );
```